# Not able to do the curl and create the REST API for Snowflake Kafka Connector

Tags: apache-kafka, apache-kafka-connect

Getting below error while doing the distributed based connectivity of the CURL command for the snowflake kafka connector:

```
curl: (7) Failed to connect to ::1: No route to host
```

the services are started from root user

```
~/kafka_2.13-2.8.0/bin$ jps 
30292 Jps 
17782 Kafka 
18984 ConsoleProducer 
1616 ConnectDistributed 
17388 QuorumPeerMain 
19357 ConsoleConsumer
```

Comment: What `curl` command are you running? Where is your Kafka Connect worker hosted?

Comment: on the same master server

Comment: Is Connect running? Show `jps` output. Can you share the curl command? Do you need IPv6 on this machine?

Comment: Yes the services are started from root user~/kafka_2.13-2.8.0/bin$ jps
30292 Jps
17782 Kafka
18984 ConsoleProducer
1616 ConnectDistributed
17388 QuorumPeerMain
19357 ConsoleConsumer

Comment: I am executing the curl in the master server and there are 2 more servers in cluster

Comment: curl: (7) Failed connect to XX.XX.XX.XXX:8083; Connection refused

Comment: Please edit your question to include the full curl command. Otherwise, looks like you fixed it https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69975067/only-see-1-worker-in-kafka-connect