# Only see 1 worker in Kafka Connect

Tags: apache-kafka, apache-kafka-connect

```
$ curl localhost:8083/connectors/file-stream-demo-distributed/status
{"name":"file-stream-demo-distributed","connector":{"state":"RUNNING","worker_id":"XX.XX.XX.XXX:8083"},"tasks":[{"id":0,"state":"RUNNING","worker_id":"XX.XX.XX.XXX:8083"}],"type":"sink"}
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to run another `connect-distributed.sh` process with the same `group.id`